# "Python has stopped working" on PyQt5 GUI exit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I've been pulling my hairs on this since a few hours. I have the following simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math

from PyQt5.QtCore import (pyqtSignal, QLineF, QPointF, QRect, QRectF, QSize,
        QSizeF, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QFont, QIcon, QIntValidator, QPainter,
        QPainterPath, QPen, QPixmap, QPolygonF)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QButtonGroup, QComboBox,
        QFontComboBox, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsLineItem, QGraphicsPolygonItem,
        QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsView, QGridLayout,
        QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QMenu, QMessageBox, QSizePolicy,
        QToolBox, QToolButton, QWidget)

class DiagramScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DiagramScene, self).__init__(parent)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.scene = DiagramScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(QRectF(0, 0, 5000, 5000))

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Diagramscene")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 500)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This program works OK. Now if you replace

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 500)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

by this (which is what you do when you want to start your program with `console_scripts`):

```
def mainFunc():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 500)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainFunc()
```

I get a segfault on exit. Althout both programs are (apparently ?) IDENTICALS.

It should be noted that if you remove the `QGraphicsView` from the application, the bug goes away. No more segfault on exit.

[image: segfault illustration]

Is the issue coming from my code ? Or is it a PyQt5 bug ?

Comment: tried your code, working fine on my end, maybe PyQt5 issue

Comment: With python 3.5 ? (Thanks for trying)

Comment: 3.6 sorry forgot to mention

Comment: If I replace all `PyQt5` imports with `PySide2`, problem goes away. So I guess that confirms it's a PyQt5 issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error, but sounds like what can happen when objects get deleted in the wrong order. This can happen when there is no parent-child relationship established (either explicitly or implicitly) for an object. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35783259/3419537) explains in more detail, and specifically mentions `QGraphicsScene`

Comment: @user3419537 I was doubtful at first, but you are absolutely right. I will answer with the modified code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed-out by @user3419537, the catch here is to **always** provide a parent on widget construction.

Otherwise, deallocation goes south and you end up with a nice segfault on program termination.

The following modified code works correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import math

from PyQt5.QtCore import (QLineF, QPointF, QRect, QRectF, QSize,
        QSizeF, Qt)
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QFont, QIcon, QIntValidator, QPainter,
        QPainterPath, QPen, QPixmap, QPolygonF)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QAction, QApplication, QButtonGroup, QComboBox,
        QFontComboBox, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsLineItem, QGraphicsPolygonItem,
        QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsTextItem, QGraphicsView, QGridLayout,
        QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QMenu, QMessageBox, QSizePolicy,
        QToolBox, QToolButton, QWidget)

class DiagramScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DiagramScene, self).__init__(parent)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Build Widgets, from top to bottom
        # Always assigning a parent to it
        ## widget is attached to MainWindow
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        ## view is attached to widget (main area of the MainWindow)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.widget)
        ## scene is attached to the view
        self.scene = DiagramScene(self.view)

        # Configure the widgets
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        # Configure the layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Diagramscene")

def mainFunc():
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 500)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainFunc()
```